# How to sequentially/separately apply the same function on array of objects?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, iteration

After successfully applying [this](https://github.com/dolphin278/genetic) genetic algorithm on single item, I wanted to optimize the values for array of objects.

In order to do that, I tried to use forEach loop the following way:

```
function getOptimalValues(req, res){
mdl.getItems({limit: 5}, function(err, items){//this function retrieves 5 items from database
    items.forEach(function (elem) {
        var queryObj = {
            properties: elem,
            targetEnergy: req.targetEnergy
        };

        genetic.getOptimalQuantities(queryObj, function (err, optimalValues) {
            geneticResults.push(optimalValues);
            if (geneticResults.length == items.length) {
                res(null, geneticResults);
            }
        });
    });
});
}
```

genetic.getOptimalQuantities is defined as follows:

```
function getOptimalQuantities(req, res){
var properties = req.properties;
var targetEnergy = req.targetEnergy;

var targetValues = {energy: targetEnergy, properties: properties};

var Task = require('genetic').Task;
var options = { getRandomSolution : getCandidateQuantities  // previously described to produce random solution
    , popSize : 100  // population size
    , stopCriteria : stopCriteria  // previously described to act as stopping criteria for entire process (set to 100 generations)
    , fitness : getFitnessValue  // previously described to measure how good your solution is
    , minimize : false  // whether you want to minimize fitness function. default is `false`, so you can omit it
    , mutateProbability : 0.1  // mutation chance per single child generation
    , mutate : mutate  // previously described to implement mutation
    , crossoverProbability : 0.3 // crossover chance per single child generation
    , crossover : crossoverFunction // previously described to produce child solution by combining two parents
};
var t = new Task(options);
t.targetValues = targetValues;
//t.on('mutate', function () { console.log('MUTATION!') });
t.on('statistics', function (statistics) {
    console.log('statistics',statistics.maxScore);
});
t.on('iteration start', function (generation) {
    console.log('iteration start - ',generation)
});
t.run(function (stats) {
    var dataObj = {quantities: stats.max, items: t.bestCombination}
    res(null, dataObj);
});
}
```

While running this procedure, I got the following output:

```
iteration start -  1
statistics 0.008126878121533886
iteration start -  1
iteration start -  1
statistics 0.007777620410591467
statistics 0.007777620410591467
iteration start -  1
iteration start -  1
iteration start -  1
statistics 0.008133385505205764
statistics 0.008133385505205764
statistics 0.008133385505205764
iteration start -  1
iteration start -  1
iteration start -  1
iteration start -  1
statistics 0.0093968469349952
statistics 0.0093968469349952
statistics 0.0093968469349952
statistics 0.0093968469349952
iteration start -  1
iteration start -  1
iteration start -  1
iteration start -  1
iteration start -  1
statistics 0.008431076204956763
statistics 0.008431076204956763
statistics 0.008431076204956763
statistics 0.008431076204956763
statistics 0.008431076204956763
iteration start -  2
iteration start -  2
iteration start -  2
iteration start -  2
iteration start -  2
...
```

For each of five items passed to function getOptimalQuantities, there should be 100 iterations and the fitness value (output as statistics) for each item on each iteration is supposed to be different (the chance of being equal for all elements is close to zero). By observing the output, therefore I guess the genetic algorithm is not running separately for each of 5 items passed in this example.

Does anyone know how to ensure the function (genetic algorithm in this case) not to mess the data from multiple inputs? Intuitively it is easier to imagine sequential execution of each call separately (that's why the reason for asking for sequential execution), but in general any suggested approach, either sequential or parallel would be very helpful.

I appreciate your help.

Niko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in the library you're using.  Its [`Task`](https://github.com/dolphin278/genetic/blob/master/lib/genetic/Task.js#L17) class inherits from node's [`EventEmitter`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/events.js) class, which contains a method named `init` that sets up a per-object listener hash.  But then `Task` overrides this method with its own `init` method:

```
Task.prototype.init = function (callback) {
  var self = this
  self.emit('init start')
  async.until(function () { return (self.population.length == self.popSize)}
    , function (callback) { self.getRandomSolution(function (solution) { self.population.push(solution); callback() }) }
    , function (err) { 
        if (err!=null) { self.emit('error', err) }
        else { 
          self.emit('init end', self.population)
      callback()
        }
      }
  )
}
```

this means `EventEmitter.init()` does not get called, which means each instance of `Task` does not have its own listener data structures but instead uses the same, global, ones.  This works fine when you have only one instance of `Task`, but as soon as you have several being processed concurrently then each of them are added to the same event listener hash and they all get notified whenever any of them emit an event.